# Odd behavior with modulo on strings

Tags: c++, cryptography, modulo, vigenere

I am applying a simple Vigenere cypher to a input file. The code I use to encrypt a single char is:

```
char CryptoModule::Vigenere(char& letter)
{
    char encryptedVal = (letter + EncryptKey_[iterator_])%128;
    iterator_ = iterator_ == EncryptKey_.size()?0:iterator_+1;
    return encryptedVal;
}
```

However, modulo is behaving very oddly. When the letter is '0' (ASCII char 48) , the key being "Chunky Peanut Butter", with the 9th char used to encrypt (char 'a', which is ASCII 97), then one would expect (48 + 97)%128 = 17. However, the result that is being returned is -52. Could someone please explain what corrections must be done to obtain the expected value ? It seems very odd that the compiler came to the conclusion that the remainder of the division 2 positive integers is a negative.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day

Comment: It's likely that the problem is that `char` is `signed` on your platform, thus you're observing overflow to negative values when you compute 48 + 97.  (Note also that signed overflow is *undefined behaviour* in C++...)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth But the arithmetic is done on `int` (promotion), no?

Comment: @jrok: Good point.  In that case, we need to see a test-case.  OP, can you construct one, please?

Comment: It's done on `int` promotion, but it's the *signed* value that's being promoted -- so you're still doing arithmetic on a negative integer. In other words, `(char)-5` promoted to int is `(int)-5`, and not `(int)0x000000<representation of -5 in char>`

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: A faster way of doing `x % 128` is `x & 0x7F` (`0x7F == 127`).

Comment: @TimČas If OP is to be believed, the values being promoted are `48` and `97`. Nothing negative there.

Comment: Whatever solution I adopt, it output positive values. Otherwise, when I try to read that info from a file, it will detect negative values and stop the loading prematurely.  But I believe OliCharlesworth is right, the char is promoted to an int to do the arithmetic.

Comment: Didn't know the trick using &, that is awesome.

Comment: Is it really any faster, though? I would imagine that the compiler would get that if it was worth changing.

Comment: Just tried static casting the result to an unsigned char before doing modulo. Still receiving the same output as before (the resulting char is the same).

Comment: @BrunoAyllon: Are you sure that maybe the input isn't getting corrupted?

Comment: @chris: Yes, a sufficiently advanced compiler will have caught that. But in case it didn't, it doesn't hurt to do so manually.

Comment: @TimČas, Well it does if it's less readable.

Comment: @TimČas Or not.  What makes you think it's faster?  That sort of thing is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @TimČas It hurts readability.  And from my experience, compilers generally produce better code when they know what you're trying to do.

Comment: The optimization aside, how should I deal with the problem ?

Comment: Could you add a `cout << (int)encryptedVal << " " << (int)letter << " " << (int)EncryptKey_[iterator_] << " " << iterator_ << endl;` before the return statement, just to check that all values are what you expect? I have a feeling that your iterator assignment condition may be off by one.

Comment: 17 48 97 9 for the line with the problematic output

Comment: Well, `encryptedVal` was correctly output as 17...

Comment: Which begs the question, why is ifstream unable to recognize the input as valid ?

Comment: This is the line ifstream reads, the last char returns -52 ASCII value, stopping the input: PZ^m>IB`Yl1gYa;p6]b[ZCFHS!5ZXX[n&MbS^@

Comment: 17 is an ASCII control character.
I don't know what system you're running on, or whether it would matter, but I do remember having a problem once sending binary data through a serial port, where sending certain numbers would end the transmission.

Comment: The problem still persists, this is a remarkably tricky bug